# libuv - What is the difference between `uv_kill` and `uv_process_kill`?

Tags: c, process, libuv

> `int uv_process_kill(uv_process_t* handle, int signum)`
>
> Sends the specified signal to the given process handle. Check the documentation on uv_signal_t — Signal handle for signal support, specially on Windows.
>
> `int uv_kill(int pid, int signum)`
>
> Sends the specified signal to the given PID. Check the documentation on uv_signal_t — Signal handle for signal support, specially on Windows.

Are these two ways of doing the exact same thing, or is the mechanism inside the library somehow different? I need to handle the error condition where my UV loop may have failed to run (for whatever reason), but I have already called `uv_spawn` for all the processes I wish to spawn.

My goal is to clean up the resources allocated to the child processes, without needing to know if the uv loop is running, stopped or in an error state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uv_process_kill` and `uv_kill` perform the same action, but they differ from each other because of their interface. The former accepts an `uv_process_t` handle while the latter requires a *pid* explicitly (both have a second argument that is a signal number).
It's worth noting that the struct `uv_process_t` (that you can use with `uv_process_kill`) has a field named `pid` (that you can use with `uv_kill`), thus one could argue that the two functions are redundant.
Anyway, the *pid* of the process to be killed could come to hand because of an external source (as an example, an user could provide it through the command line - think at how the *kill* tool works on Linux). Therefore, there is no guarantee that you have an instance of `uv_process_t` whenever you have a *pid* and it goes without saying that the two functions serve slightly different purposes.
Of course, you can still use `uv_kill` when you have an instance of `uv_process_t` as:

```
uv_kill(proc.pid);
```

Anyway this is not the way libuv works and you should ever use the functions that accept `uv_*` data structures when you have them, for they know how to tear down everything correctly.

To sum up, you can think at `uv_process_kill` as a more libuv oriented function to be used when you are in charge of the whole lifecycle of the process (you spawn it and you kill it if needed). On the other side, `uv_kill` is a more general purpose function to be used when you want to deal with processes of which you know the *pid* but for which you don't have a properly initialized `uv_process_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the source ([here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/win/process.c#L1241) and [here](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/win/process.c#L1259)). `uv_process_kill` and `uv_kill` do the same thing.

Comment: Remove "There is a member uv_process_t.pid in the type uv_process_t.", and also provide a link to the source (you refer to in your answer) and I will give you the checkmark.